# Passing item.name in StackNavigator React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

So i have a flatList that display names using Fetch api,

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress {()=>NavigationService.navigate('Med') }>

      <Text> {item.name}</Text>)}
```

on the click on one of the name i navigate to another screen where i wil have to use "item.name", how can i pass this param.on that screen code i'm using a class and i don't want to use a function.

```
class search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }.....
```

thanks in advance

Comment: could you share your ```NavigationService```?

Comment: @SDushan https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Answer (score 0):

check hope it will work
now here is pass your item.name in this navigate action

```
  <FlatList
              data={this.state.data}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress {()=>NavigationService.navigate(`${item.name}`) }>

          <Text> {item.name}</Text>)}
```

Comment: unfortunatly no, couldn't find variable:item on the other screen

Comment: oh, okay no problem '

Comment: So can you please tell which screen you want show this "item",then i will know

Comment: look at the description, when i navigate to screen Med (onPress {()=>NavigationService.navigate('Med')) i will use the param in a function like this' bringName(item.name)'

Comment: HI , i m clearly understand but hope its works:
navigation.navigate('Med',{
                        bringName: somaData
                      })
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
and use this code which component where you need to show name

 const paramName = this.props.navigation.state.params.bringName

thanks

Comment: hi thank you for your feed back,i didn't understand this this.props.navigation.state.params.bringName, what state are you refering to?

Comment: No problem brother 

Comment: Hi, its navigation state value

Answer (score 0):

Since your `NavigationService` handle `navigate` function with params as below,

```
export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

You can pass your params as

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress {() => NavigationService.navigate('Med', {name: item.name})}>
```

Once you navigate to the specific screen you can access you `name` params as

```
this.props.route.params.name
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: i tried it and got this error,' typeError: undefined is not an object(this.props.navigation.route.params.name), what could've gone wrong?.thank you

Comment: @AymenAymen it should be ```this.props.route.params.name```

Comment: still got the same error, should i declare something first?

Comment: @AymenAymen what was the error that you are getting?

Comment: typeError: undefined is not an object(this.props.route.params.name)

Comment: which version of react-navigation that you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211158/discussion-between-sdushan-and-aymen-aymen).

Comment: Try this.props.navigation.getParam('name')